# How do I change browser page when ATUreporter does not take screenshos on failed tests

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, testng

I failed test intentionally just to see if it takes screenshot, the element password_field can't be located on the webpage,

because I gave it wrong xpath - passwordqqq(look up comment in the code below)

when test fails it must take screenshot, but it does not,

so I want to change browser page using setCaptureScreen method,

I looked up the api here, but it s poorly documented.

The code below does this:

- assert 2 fields(password, phone) are displayed
- not null
- clear every field
- type in phone
- type in password
- assert it stays on same page, if password/phone is invalid

  ```
  package erjan.testNG.personal_cabinet_login;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;

  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

  import org.testng.Assert;

  import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;

  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
  import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
  import atu.testng.reports.ATUReports;
  import atu.testng.reports.utils.Utils;
  import atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener;
  import atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener;
  import atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener;
  import atu.testng.reports.logging.LogAs;
  import atu.testng.selenium.reports.CaptureScreen;
  import atu.testng.selenium.reports.CaptureScreen.ScreenshotOf;

  @Listeners({ ATUReportsListener.class, ConfigurationListener.class,
  MethodListener.class })

  public class Login_test_no_user {

      {
          System.setProperty("atu.properties", 
   "C:\\Users\\www\\ERJAN_NAIMIKZ_ALL\\erjan_2_naimikz_test\\ATUReporter_Selenium_testNG_5.5 BETA");
      }

        WebDriver firefox ;
        @Test
        public void main() {
        setAuthorInfoForReports();
        setIndexPageDescription();

        WebElement phone_field = null ;
        WebElement password_field = null ;

        //setCaptureScreenBrowserpage

        ATUReports.add("checking phone, password fields are displayed", "--", "--", "--", LogAs.INFO,null);

        try{
         phone_field= firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/div[1]/span/input"));

        Assert.assertNotNull(phone_field);
        Assert.assertNotNull(password_field);

        Assert.assertTrue(phone_field.isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertTrue(password_field.isDisplayed());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ATUReports.add("a field is invisible or not available", LogAs.FAILED, new CaptureScreen(
                    ScreenshotOf.BROWSER_PAGE)); 
        }

        ATUReports.add("phone, password are visible",LogAs.PASSED,null);

        ATUReports.add("inputting number", "0009999999", "--", "--", LogAs.INFO,null);
        phone_field.clear();
        phone_field.sendKeys("0009999999");

        ATUReports.add("inputting password", "bad_password!!!22222", "--", "--", LogAs.INFO,null);
        password_field.clear();
        password_field.sendKeys("bad_password!!!22222");

        ATUReports.add("click LOGIN button", "--", "--", "--", LogAs.INFO,null);
        firefox.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button.blue")).click();

        String newUrl = firefox.getCurrentUrl();

        ATUReports.add("check URL", "astana/login", "astana/login", "--", LogAs.INFO,null);
        try{
            Assert.assertEquals("http://test.naimi.me/astana/login", newUrl);  
        }catch(Exception e ){
            ATUReports.add("webpages are not same!", LogAs.FAILED, new CaptureScreen(
                    ScreenshotOf.BROWSER_PAGE)); 
        }

        ATUReports.add("page is same",LogAs.PASSED,null);

    }

    private void setAuthorInfoForReports() {
         ATUReports.setAuthorInfo("NAIMI.KZ AUTOTEST", Utils.getCurrentTime(),"1.0");
      }

    private void setIndexPageDescription() {
        ATUReports.indexPageDescription = "erjan runs ATUreport";
  }


    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() throws IOException {     

        firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
        ATUReports.setWebDriver(firefox);


        firefox.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        firefox.get("http://test.naimi.me/astana/login"); 

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        firefox.quit();
    }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use `Exception`. There are specyfic hendlers for example:

```
@Test
public void sc01_2252015(){
    int x = 9, y = 10;

    try{
        Assert.assertEquals(x, y);
    }catch (AssertionError e) {
        System.err.println("NO!");
        throw new TestNGException("Error: " + e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("NOPE!");
        throw new TestNGException("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

`NOPE!` will do not execute

Comment: but statment is returning exception? maybe it is something wrong with listener? `ATUReports` is making screenshot normally in correct test? for example in `try{}` block?

Comment: yes it  does detect it and show it failed in html report ,but no screenshot, let me do screenshots in try block, when assert fails,